# $n$ such that $|\sin in | > 10 000$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

An exercise in my book asks me to find $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $|\sin in |> 10 000$.

> Could someone please check my solution?

I wrote

$$ |\sin in |^2 = \cosh^2 n + \sinh^2 n = 1 + 2 \sinh^2 n$$

hence $|\sin in |> 10 000$ if and only if

$$ \sinh n > {\sqrt{9 999}\over \sqrt{2}}$$

> Is it correct like this or is it possible to find $n$ $more explicitly
>   (without using a calculator)?

Comment: Correct. $|\sin in|=\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}$, $\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}>10000 \Leftarrow e^n > 20000 \Leftrightarrow n>\log(2)+4\log(10)$ more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the point.  Write $\sin (in)$ in terms of $e^n$ and $e^{-n}$.  As you leave the origin along one of the axes, one of the terms dominates.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$\sinh n=\dfrac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}$$ Solve a inequality for $e^n.$ Good Luck.

Comment: @2mkgz "This does not provide an answer to the question." I beg your pardon?

Answer (score 0):

We have the set of equalities

$$|\sin (in)|=|\frac{e^{i(in)}-e^{-i(in)}}{2i}|=|\frac{e^{-n}-e^{n}}{2i}|=|\sinh (n)|$$

Note that $\sinh(n) = \frac12 (e^{n}-e^{-n})$.  Thus, if we let $x=e^{n}$, then

$$|\sinh (n)| = 1000$$

implies that

$$x^2-2000x-1=0$$

whereupon solving for $n$ gives

$$n=\log(1000+\sqrt{10^6+1})$$